# How to get substring (x,y) location from UILabel text (iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone

How to get substring (x,y) location from UILabel text (iPhone SDK) ?

For example:

I am having a multiline label which is placed on View.

Now i want to get (origin.x,origin.y) location of any substring of UILabel.text , Is it possible ? How ?

I have try goggling but not found any soln yet.

Comment: Your question isn't especially clear. Are you trying to scan the text and pick out numbers in the format: `(str1, str2)` ? or what?